# partner specific javascript file output based on configuration /gruntjs

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

We have two main core components of javascript which we give it to multiple partners.
1. Core Module that doesn't change
2. Partner Specific module that will be based on partner.

I need to write a gruntjs by combining core + partner specific file and share it with partners.  we have 100 different partners with varied combinations. 
other than this we have regular custom  analytics, signup module files which has just one version which needs building management treatment as well.

1. wanted to know what is the best practices to handle things in Grunt .

Answer (score 1):

I think that the Grunt project best practice is to handle one project, declare tasks to be used as your task manager and just use some plugins as helpers.

If you still want to use Grunt for doing a complex project you can see [grunt-hub](https://github.com/shama/grunt-hub) for managing Grunt projects.

A personal opinion, use pure Nodejs module for that kind of job (Look in [npmjs.org](https://npmjs.org/) you might find already done modules) and finally use Grunt for externalize specific tasks.